# When is $20q^4-40q^3+30q^2-10q$ a square for positive integer $q$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

> For what $q$ is the following polynomial a square?
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> &20q^4-40q^3+30q^2-10q\\
> =\:&10q(q - 1)(2q^2 - 2q + 1)
> &q\in\mathbb N
> \end{align}
> $$

I know of two single cases, $q=1$ gives $0$ and $q = 2$ gives $100$. I tested $3\le q\le12$ and found none.

This is what I've tried so far:

I found that
$$
\begin{align}
\gcd(q,q - 1) &= 1\\
\gcd(q, 2q^2 - 2q + 1) &= 1\\
\gcd(q - 1, 2q^2 - 2q + 1) &= 1
\end{align}
$$
The problem is the same as determining whether there exists a $t\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$
q(q - 1)(2q^2 - 2q + 1) = 10t^2
$$
If $q$ is even, write $q=2p$ and say
$$
p(2p-1)(8p^2-4p+1) = 5t^2
$$
The residues modulo $5$ are as follows
$$
\begin{align}
p\equiv0\pmod{5}\implies p(2p-1)(8p^2-4p+1)\equiv0\pmod{5}\\
p\equiv1\pmod{5}\implies p(2p-1)(8p^2-4p+1)\equiv0\pmod{5}\\
p\equiv2\pmod{5}\implies p(2p-1)(8p^2-4p+1)\equiv0\pmod{5}\\
p\equiv3\pmod{5}\implies p(2p-1)(8p^2-4p+1)\equiv0\pmod{5}\\
p\equiv4\pmod{5}\implies p(2p-1)(8p^2-4p+1)\equiv4\pmod{5}
\end{align}
$$
Which means that $p\not\equiv4\pmod5$, and we now need to test if it's a square in the rest of the cases.

---

**Case r = 5p**

In this case we are solving $r\cdot(10r - 1)(200r^2 - 20r + 1) = t^2$ and since the factors are coprime, they must all be squares, however modulo $7$ atleast one factor is not one of the quadratic residues for all cases.

---

**Case r = 5p + 1**

In this case we are solving $(5r+1)(10r+1)(40r^2+12 r+1) = t^2$ and since the factors are coprime, they must all be squares, however modulo $3$ atleast one factor is not one of the quadratic residues for cases $1$ and $2$, and the last case $0$ we have an observed solution at $q=2$, however for $q=12$ we don't get a square, so it remains to prove whether there are other than $r=0$ which are square.

---

At this point I stopped because there are many cases, and I don't know how to prove that it is only for $r=0$ when $r=5p+1$ that the polynomial is square, or if there are other such $r$.

**So the thing I'm asking specifically is:** Is there a more elegant way, and if not, how do I prove that the observed cases are the only solutions (or if not, what is the set of solutions).

Comment: You can telescope the equation a little more. Let a =q(q-1)

Answer (score 5):

Let $r=q(q-1)/2$, then $8r^2+2r=10t^2$, $(8r+1)^2=80t^2+1$.  So you might solve the Pellian equation $k^2=80t^2+1$, and then try see if any of the $k$ have the right form in terms of $q$.

Answer (score 0):

A similar Pell approach.

We want solutions to

$$10q(q-1)(2q^2-2q+1)=n^2$$

So $q\in{0,1}$ with $n=0$ are trivial examples. We might get solutions as linear combinations of these.

Let $2p=q(q-1)$.

Then $$5(4p)(4p+1)=n^2$$

We know $n$ must be a multiple of 5, so let n=5k.

$$5(4p)(4p+1)=25k^2$$

$$(4p)^2+4p=5k^2$$

Let x=4p and Complete the square:

$$(x)^2+x+\frac{1}{4}=5k^2+\frac{1}{4}$$

$$ (x+\frac{1}{2})^2-5k^2=\frac{1}{4} $$

Then multiply by 5: 
$$(2x+1)^2-5(2k)^2=1$$

Since $x=4p$, and $2p=q(q-1)$,

$$[4q(q-1)+1]^2-5(2k)^2=1$$
With factoring:

$$ (2q-1)^4-5(2k)^2=1$$

We get a Pell equation: $m^2-5n^2=1$

Initial values for $(m,n)=(9,4)$ implying $q=2$ and $k=2$, so $n=10$

Then you can apply the Brahmagupta Solution to Pell's equation which allows one to generate infinitely many solutions from a single one.

Given $x^2-py^2=1$ and solution $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$x_{n+1}=x_0x_n+py_0y_n$$
$$y_{n+1}=y_0x_n+x_0y_n$$

So you want $x_n$ that are odd perfect squares.

Answer (score 0):

We are asked to find positive integer values for $q$ such that $(2q-1)^4 = 80 t^2 + 1$ for some integer $t$. The complete answer can be found with the help of a result of J.H.E. Cohn, The Diophantine equation x^4 −Dy^2 = 1 II. Acta Arith. 78 (1997), 401--403.
doi: 10.4064/aa-78-4-401-403, freely accessible at
[source](https://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa78/aa7847.pdf): For a positive integer $d$, let the fundamental solution of the equation $v^2 −du^2 =
1$ be $a + b\sqrt{d}$. Then the only possible solutions in positive integers of the equation $X^4 −dY ^2 = 1$ are
given by $X^2 = a$ and $X^2 = 2 a^2 −1$.

In our case we have $d=80$, $a=9$, so that $2q -1 =3$ is the only possibility. Thus, we obtain $q=2$.

The other solution $q=1$ comes from the solution $X=1$, $Y=0$.

If we are looking for all integer values of $q$, then we have the additional solutions $q=0$ and $q=-1$, coming from $2q-1=-1$ and $2q-1=-3$, respectively.